# How to query MySQL to build Nginx configuration file?

Tags: mysql, nginx

Is it possible to have a MySQL query in my Nginx config?

For example:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        $domain = [a way to get the current domain];
        $server_info = [a way to do the query (by $domain) and have some info returned];
        server_name $serverinfo;
        [do stuff]
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [NginX module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-mysql-module) (might be a bit outdated btw)

Answer (score 1):

(Answer by @jOk)
You can use the NginX moudule located at https://github.com/arut/nginx-mysql-module which allows you to do exactly what you are asking to do.